# Fringe Fields in a Cylindrical Capacitor v/s Parallel Plate Capacitors

Tags: electric-fields, capacitance, geometry

I understand that Fringe Fields exist on the edges of a parallel plate capacitor like so:
[image: fringe]

1. I was trying to figure out if a Cylindrical Capacitor would have fringe fields as well, and how they would look like (presuming it is a cylinder of a reasonable radius and finite length). In this image, I would think that that the fringe fields would exist along the pink arrows shown, but coming outward:

[image: cylinder]

2. Which geometry between the two would allow the capacitor to have less fringe fields?

I understand that this may be a difficult to question to answer without the actual dimensions, but I was wondering if there was any general statements that could be made about fringe fields of cylindrical capacitors?